# generate dynamic gallery jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, json

Im working in a personal project and I have troubles generating the proper markup with jQuery.

I have an action that return a list of images to display in this json structure

```
[{
    "Id": imageid,
    "imagePath": path to image,
    "imageThumbnailPath": path of the thumbnail,
    "imageTitle": image title,
    "imageSubtitle": image subtitle,
    "CategoryId": id of the category
}]
```

So I want to dinamically generate the markup in order to show the different images. I'm working with a bootstrap template and this is what I have to generate:

```
<div class="span3">
    <div class="picture">
        <a href="path to image" rel="image" title="image title">
            <img src="path to thumbnail" alt="" class="customgalleryclass"  />
        <div class="image-overlay-zoom"></div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-description">
        <h5><a href="#">image title</a></h5>
        <p>image subtitle</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to generate the proper markup with jQuery append, wrapInner, etc. But since I don't understand it very well its generating a mess.

Thank you!

Comment: please show the code that generates a mess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't share the code where its generating a mess.

if you just don't know how to do it please search for "jquery template json". it will be a good start. you can find hundred of ways to do it.

quick example i'll use jquery and 
http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js

thanks to http://www.borismoore.com/2010/10/jquery-templates-is-now-official-jquery.html

you can find the working example at http://jsfiddle.net/marathonman/EkVvS/

**HTML**

```
    <div id="myGallery"></div>
```

**TEMPLATE**

```
    <script id="myGalleryTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <div class="span3">
        <div class="picture">
            <a href="${imagePath}" rel="image" title="${imageTitle}">
                <img src="${imageThumbnailPath}" alt="" class="customgalleryclass"  />
            <div class="image-overlay-zoom"></div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item-description">
            <h5><a href="#">${imageTitle}</a></h5>
            <p>${imageSubtitle}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </script>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
    var images = [
    {
        "Id": "imageid",
        "imagePath": "path to image",
        "imageThumbnailPath": "path of the thumbnail",
        "imageTitle": "image title",
        "imageSubtitle": "image subtitle",
        "CategoryId": "id of the category"
    }
    ];

    $( "#myGalleryTemplate" ).tmpl(images).appendTo( "#myGallery" );
```

Comment: I used jQuery Templates and it worked like a charm! Thanks! I didn't know about that.

Comment: @wOvalle i'm happy to hear that it works for you. my answer only an example. jQuery Templates plugin will remain beta. but i think no cons to use for templating. but if you interested in data binging templates please search for jsrender, angular, knockout, mustache, hadlebars, hogan, dust, underscore etc.